# Why do I receive error in statement in r? What do I need to change in my function?

Tags: r, function, return

What do I need to change in my # Function to Get Google Ads Data so as to avoid the below statement error? It is not clear from the error log what I need to change in order to troubleshoot it. Will be grateful for any help.Select fields, ReportName and Date return the correct data. I can post that here if it helps.

```
    library(plyr)
    library(RCurl)
    library(Radwords)
    library(odbc)
    library(DBI)
    library(dplyr)
    library(rgoogleads)
    
# Function to Get Google Ads Data
getAdwordsData <- function(SelectFields, ReportName, StartDate, EndDate){
  
  body <- statement(select=SelectFields,
                    report=ReportName,
                    start=as.character(StartDate),
                    end=as.character(EndDate))
  
  AdwordsDataTotal <- data.frame()
  
  for (i in 1:nrow(adwordsAccounts)) {
    
    dataRaw <- getData(clientCustomerId = adwordsAccounts[i,]$ClientCustomerId, 
                       google_auth = google_auth , statement = body, 
                       apiVersion = "201809", 
                       transformation = FALSE, 
                       changeNames = TRUE,
                       includeZeroImpressions = FALSE, 
                       verbose = FALSE)
    
    dataTransformed <- transformData (dataRaw, report=ReportName)
    
    # Add account info
    if (nrow(dataTransformed) > 0) {
      dataTransformed <- cbind(dataTransformed, 
                               CustomerId = adwordsAccounts[i,]$ClientCustomerId, 
                               AccountName = adwordsAccounts[i,]$AccountName
      )
      
      AdwordsDataTotal <- rbind(dataTransformed,AdwordsDataTotal)
    }
  }
  
  return(AdwordsDataTotal)
}



ReportName = "CLICK_PERFORMANCE_REPORT"
SelectFields <- gads_get_report(
  resource    = "click_view",
  fields      = c("click_view.gclid","ad_group.id","campaign.id","segments.date"),
  date_from   = Sys.Date(),
  date_to     = Sys.Date()
  #where       = "ad_group.status = 'ENABLED'
)

SelectFields <- unlist(colnames(SelectFields))
####Rename columns so that they become compatible with metric list for report names (report = "CLICK_PERFORMANCE_REPORT")


SelectFields <- SelectFields %>% rename(CampaignId = campaign_id, AdGroupId = ad_group_id,GclId = click_view_gclid)


for (i in 1:nrow(dates)) {
  FactAdWordsClickPerformanceLoop <- getAdwordsData(ReportName,SelectFields,dates[i,],dates[i,])
  FactAdWordsClickPerformance <- rbind(FactAdWordsClickPerformance,FactAdWordsClickPerformanceLoop)
}
Error in statement(select = SelectFields, report = ReportName, start = as.character(StartDate),  : 
  c("177373599", "177373599", "177373599", "177373599", "177373599", "177373599", "177373599" ,
Called from: statement(select = SelectFields, report = ReportName, start = as.character(StartDate), 
    end = as.character(EndDate))
```

Comment: is the getdata function is from the rgoogleads lib?

Comment: it is from Radwords package

Comment: Without data it is hard to trouble shoot this for you. The problem seems to be in the call to statement(). So instead of running it as a function, set values for the function parameters (SelectFields, etc.) and then just run the statement function. This is what you need to troubleshoot. It seems like it might be your data.

Comment: what data would be helpful? i can post the dataframe you think would be helpful. i did not because it would be too long and no one would look at my post in SO. Please let me know which data you think would be helpful from the dfs and i will post it.Thanks